# aws-cdk: pass ENV to NextJS app throught Ec2TaskDefinition

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

My node.js app needs creds and an endpoint to a DB. I deploy the app using cdk and Ec2TaskDefinition. With ECS.ContainerDefinition.addEnvironment(...) I pass env's to a Docker container. Dockerfile has a multistage type where in the last stage I gather all required envs into a string for future usage in NextJS app.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16-alpine AS deps
#Skiped code
#....
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16-alpine AS runner

ENV DATABASE_URL=postgresql://${DB_USERNAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_ENDPOINT}/postgres?schema=public

EXPOSE 8081
CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start", "-p", "8081"]
```

But in the next app instead of proper formed string I get something like this:

> postgresql://:@/postgres?schema=public

All ENV's are empty. But I can see all required envs in Task definition Web interface on Amazon. Seems that I need to transfer them to Docker somehow...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use environment variables declared in the cdk with `addEnvironment` as components in your `ENV` declarations in your dockerfile. This is because the `ENV` command is executed at *build time* and environment variables provided by the CDK (actually in your task definition) are only available at *runtime*, not at build time.

To work around this, there's maybe a couple approaches:

1. Set the whole variable in your cdk app OR
2. Use an entrypoint to form the `DATABASE_URL` at runtime.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# /docker-entrypoint.sh

export DATABASE_URL="postgresql://${DB_USERNAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_ENDPOINT}/postgres?schema=public"

exec "$@"
```

Then in your dockerfile, do the following:

```
# ...
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16-alpine AS runner

EXPOSE 8081
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh 

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start", "-p", "8081"]
```

This way, you will create the variable at runtime, when all your other variables are available.

---

Also, you should NOT use `addEnvironment` for secrets. Otherwise, you're exposing that sensitive data in your task definition as plaintext. Use the `secrets` parameter to add secrets from AWS secrets manager or S3 when creating the container instead.